# Does Linux uses the device files for the HDD partitions to access the HDD?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have found the following image on the web:

[image]

What I understand from this image is that if for example **Process 1** wants to read some file, it will do the following:

- Call `read()` and pass the file descriptor for the file as argument to
  `read()`.
- The Virtual File System will check to see on what filesystem type the
  file resides on, let's say that it resides on an ext2 filesystem.
- The ext2 driver (don't know if it's called "driver") will ask the
  appropriate device driver to retrieve the file from the HDD.

Now what I want to know is: what does the "Device driver" box in the image represent, does it represent device files such as `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sdb1`, etc.?

So basically does Linux actually uses these device files to access the HDD (i.e. when Linux wants to read some file, does it call `open()` on the `/dev/sda1` device file and then read from the returned file descriptor), or are these device files only available for the users and programs to use them, and Linux uses some other means to access the HDD partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So basically does Linux actually uses these device files to access the HDD (i.e. when Linux wants to read some file, does it call `open()` on the `/dev/sda1` device file and then read from the returned file descriptor), or are these device files only available for the users and programs to use them, and Linux uses some other means to access the HDD partitions?

No.

The Linux kernel is *implementing [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)*; it is *not* directly *using them*.

[System calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) make sense only in [user-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) application code. Kernel code is running in kernel mode. Read about [CPU modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes).

Of course, [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ing then [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing some disk partition like `/dev/sda1` *indirectly* involves some *kernel* code which is shared and used by other kernel code (eg notably by the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) and [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) code).

> are these device files only available for the users and programs to use them, and Linux uses some other means to access the HDD partitions?

Yes, kernel code don't use device files such as [sd(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/sd.4.html) (but some code layer is shared somewhere). Kernel don't use (but just *provides* to user processes when they use system calls) [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) and deal with kernel [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and other data (dentries, vfsmounts, ...). Some other kind of inodes are written on the disk by the file system layer.

> what does the "Device driver" box in the image represent,

It represent kernel code (read [device driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) wikipage) related to [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) disks and to your [chipset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipset).

**Read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)** (freely downloadable) since an entire book is required to explain all that. Then see [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) for Linux kernel specific things and study the kernel source code (it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)) from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/)

<sup>(this is a gross simplification; kernel code is modular and organized in software layers, such as [VFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system), SATA bus, etc....)</sup>

Comment: This might be getting into too much detail, but instead of saying the kernel deals with inodes, it would be more accurate (for Linux) to say that the kernel deals with directory entries (dentries), inodes, and vfsmounts. (You need all three to represent all the data involved in using a file descriptor.)